# fitting training data from decision tree regressor causes crash

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Trying to implement the decision tree regressor algorithm on some training data but when I call fit() I get an error.

```
    (trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

    vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["_1", "_2", "_3", "_4", "_5", "_6", "_7", "_8", "_9", "_10"], outputCol="features")

    dt = DecisionTreeRegressor(featuresCol="features", labelCol="_11")

    dt_model = dt.fit(trainingData)
```

Generates the error

```
  File "spark.py", line 100, in <module>
    main()
  File "spark.py", line 87, in main
    dt_model = dt.fit(trainingData)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 132, in fit
    return self._fit(dataset)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 295, in _fit
    java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 292, in _fit_java
    return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Column features must be of type struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> but was actually struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>.'
```

But the data structures are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing two steps. 1. transformation part, and 2. selecting features and label from the transformed data. I assume the data contains only numerical data, i.e. no categorical data. I am going to write down a generic flow of training a model using `pyspark.ml` to help you.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier

#date processing part

vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(input_cols=['col_1','col_2',...,'col_10'],outputCol='features')

#you missed these two steps
trans_data = vecAssembler.transform(data)

final_data = trans_data.select('features','col_11') #your label column name is col_11

train_data, test_data = final_data.randomSplit([0.7,0.3])

#ml part

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(featuresCol='features',labelCol='col_11')

dt_model = dt.fit(train_data)

dt_predictions = dt_model.transform(test_data)

#proceed with the model evaluation part after this
```